# "with" preposition at the beginning or at the end of a sentence

Tags: prepositions, relative-clauses

Which is correct:

> 1. This is the most beautiful programming language **with that** I ever worked!

or,

> 2. This is the most beautiful programming language **that** I ever worked **with**!

Answer (score 4):

I agree with saintjules and I'd just like to add that this sentence can be said correctly in four ways:

1. This is the most beautiful programming language **with which** I ever worked!
2. This is the most beautiful programming language **which** I ever worked **with**!
3. This is the most beautiful programming language **that** I ever worked **with**!
4. This is the most beautiful programming language () I ever worked **with**!

Only *which* and not *that* can be used directly after a preposition in these constructions. If the preposition *with* takes the end position then either *which* or *that* can be used. If *which/that* is used in place of an object it can be omitted, but if it's replacing the subject it cannot.

- They replaced the programming language which/that I like so much.
- They replaced the programming language I like so much.

But:

- They replaced the programming language which/that was my favourite one.
- *They replaced the programming language was my favourite one. (ungrammatical).

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the grammatical correctness of the two sentences given, only the second is acceptable, in that it shows a relative clause in its more informal usage, i.e. the relative pronoun "that" + the preposition "with" which is shifted to the end of the sentence. Notice that in this case, the relative pronoun may be dropped since it functions as an object in the relative clause.

The first sentence is more formal, but in order to be grammatically correct it should read as follows:

> This is the most beautiful programming language with **which** I ever
>   worked!