# should I use "to" before which?

Tags: sentence-structure

I read a speaking book and I saw this sentence:

> I am planning to pursue my education in Australia and the university
>   **to** which I have applied requires IELTS score 7 to let me get in.

but I dont understand "to" role before "which" in this sentence

Comment: It should become clear if you think about that clause as a standalone sentence: *I have to applied to a university*. (and *The university requires ...*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check out [relative pronouns](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_relative_clauses) first

After you got that, you should know that the `which` after `to` refers to the university. And that the original sentence,

> a) I am planning to pursue my education in Australia and the university to which I have applied requires IELTS score 7 to let me get in.

, can be rewritten and divided into two sentences. Notice the bold to of the second sentence.

> b) I am planning to pursue my education in Australia.
>   c) The university I have applied requires IELTS score 7 to let me get in **to**.

Merging the two sentences above using the relative pronoun, *which*, to refer to *the university*, we get

> d) I am planning to pursue my education in Australia and *the university* *which* I have applied requires IELTS score 7 to let me get in **to**.

Notice how *which* serves both as a conjunction and a pronoun for *the university* And note that the bold **to** is still at the same position as it was in sentence c). Next, just by the grammar rule (see the [Wikipedia page](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_relative_clauses) I suggested in the beginning at -> Overview -> 6. for more details or [here](http://www.edufind.com/english-grammar/preposition-placement-relative-clauses/) for more examples), we can move that preposition, **to**, to just before *which*. Then we're done!

> a) I am planning to pursue my education in Australia and the university to which I have applied requires IELTS score 7 to let me get in.

Key takeaways here: the sole reason that the **to** is there because it was part of the original seperated sentence b), and because in b), you `get in to` a university, the purpose of `to` is just for collocation. To `get in to` a university is just an expression of saying that you're accepted by a university.

Answer (score 3):

The *to* does not really have to do anything with *which* here and it can even be placed on several different places in the sentence. The reason it's there is because the verb in the subclause is *to apply **to** (a university)*.

You can place it on different places:

> - ...the university **to** which I have applied...
> - ...the university which I have applied **to**...

Or with *that* instead of *which*, though the preposition then only has one possible place:

> - ...the university that I have applied **to**...

Maybe the difference becomes clearer when I use a verb with a different preposition, for example *to study **at** (a university)*:

> - The university **at** which I am currently studying.
> - The university which I am currently studying **at**.

Answer (score 2):

**[To apply to or to apply for](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/apply)**

> 1request [intransitive]    to make a formal request, usually written, for something such as a job, a place in a university, or permission to do something
>   apply for
>
> *She applied for a job with the local newspaper.*
>
> *We need to    apply for   planning    permission  to build a garage.*
>
> **apply to**
>
> ***I applied to four universities and was accepted by all of them.***

I'd call it a [collocation](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/collocation); in English you simply have to remember (learn by usage that is) the combinations of prepositions that follow verbs in certain contexts.

---

If you are confused why the preposition *to* is preceding the word *which* - in your example *which* is a relative pronoun, that (which) stands in the place of 'university' as Damkerng T. pointed out. "To" can be moved to the end-position (you can put it at the end of the sentence while retaining the same meaning). You can find examples of that in [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/56923/with-preposition-at-the-beginning-or-at-the-end-of-a-sentence/57008#57008).