# Prepositions at the end

Tags: prepositions

If we are to avoid placing a preposition at the end then which is correct? The original is **Whom will you come with?**

- Whom with will you come?
- With whom will you come?

Comment: I would use the latter. I have a name for such a construction; we call it a pied-piping. I don't know whether the former is possible or not, but I recommend you not use it.

Comment: *Whom with will you come?* is not grammatical. Informal/conversational: *Who are you coming with?*  Formal: *With whom will you come?* Very informal: *I heard you were coming. Who with?*

Comment: I mean "we have a name"

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["with" preposition at the beginning or at the end of a sentence](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/56923/with-preposition-at-the-beginning-or-at-the-end-of-a-sentence)

Answer (score 2):

*"With whom will you come?"* is correct.

Keep in mind, though, that "whom" is not as commonly used in modern English, and is rarely used in American English.  "Who" is an acceptable substitute.

Also keep in mind that some consider the rule against ending a sentence with a preposition to be entirely artificial and pointless.  See [this article in Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/prepositions-ending-a-sentence-with) for more information on the argument, or [this video](https://www.merriam-webster.com/video/ending-a-sentence-with-a-preposition).

To some speakers, rearranging a sentence to avoid the terminal preposition (and use "whom" instead of "who") sounds like "proper" English.  To others, it sounds pompous and pretentious, and it's more natural to simply say:

> Who are you going with?

Or, if you want to avoid the terminal preposition:

> Who is coming with you? / Who are you bringing?

Comment: Yeh, I know about the rule, I just sometimes want to use a different way.

Comment: @SovereignSun Me too -- but because I'm American I have to carefully consider when and where and **with whom** I use this grammar.  :)

Comment: I am not American, I am not even close to being an American but I understand you perfectly well.

Comment: @SovereignSun in general, Americans like "plain talk".  We do have a wide range of slang, but, outside of formal situations, we tend to avoid fancy grammar that would be commonplace in the UK.  So, when I say "I have to carefully consider" what I say, it means I think about the audience and whether they appreciate me using that grammar, or if they think I'm just showing off.

Comment: @SovereignSun - You wrote: "I am not American, I am not even close to being an American but I understand you perfectly well." Do you really feel sorry for not being the one? A Russian myself, I'm really proud of all my countrymen actively participating in the process this site has once been built for. Your enthusiasm is praiseworthy and most of your questions are worth to be up-voted. As for this one, to me, it seems like a question asked just for the sake of asking about something that is obviously known to you. No offense meant whatsoever, and not my down-vote, I swear. The best.

Comment: @Rompey I ssid that although I am not American I can understand Andrew. I also carefully consider when and where to use certain grammar and words. I asked this because I wanted to know if the first us possible. There's always a purpose why I ask a question.